# Why subdivided faces with smooth shading acting weird?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have this model, and when I add the subdivision-modifier:

[image]

it seems to be okay, for me (I guess those bumps are there, because of the triangle faces instead of quads):

[image]

but when I add the smooth-shading I'm having this:

[image]

I think this is something really obvious -- but I just can't figure out the reason..

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is your object [normals](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces#Normals) are facing the different directions at these edges. To fix, go into *Edit* mode, select the mesh and recalculate normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, Or you could manually select faces and flip the normals.

You can often confirm or investigate most most odd looking artifacts on your models by enabling a normal display type under *Mesh Display* in the *Toolshelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>). On a clean model, depending on the use case, both the vertex and face normals should point outwards.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out, a few minutes before you, although I started to flip the normals manually -- thanks for the global `recalculate` tip:)

Comment: Enabling backface culling is also a good way to quickly spot flipped normals.